# FileWriter won't append new lines

Tags: java, newline, jfilechooser, filewriter, swingx

I'm not sure why my output function isn't picking up newlines when it creates a file. Here is the code:

```
private void outputToFile(){
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setSelectedFile(new File("frequency.txt"));
    int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    try{
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
      String out = this.toString();
      writer.append(out);
      writer.flush();
      writer.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println("Cancelled and aborted");
    }
  }
```

My toString method works fine when I print to the command line, but drops all instances of \n in the file output. Here is a sample "broken" output from this function (this is a frequency counter)

Output File:
Q: 5
\n: 7
C: 1
a: 5
t: 6
s: 3
(space): 6
r: 1
e: 4
c: 1
o: 2
l: 3
.: 2
W: 1
,: 1
h: 4
': 1
w: 1
y: 3
\t: 1
R: 1
i: 1
g: 1
?: 1
B: 1
!: 1

There should be new lines after each number there.

If you want the full group of my classes, here they are: http://pastebin.com/CCLLBUqF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing the file, you need to include both a newline and a linefeed character.
So, in your `toString()` method, where you add the `"\n"` newline, instead add both a linefeed and newline: `"\r\n"`

Comment: Ideally you should use System.getProperty("line.separator"); instead of a platform dependent line seperator character

Comment: Hm. I tried using both "\r" and the System.getproperty method, and both have failed. The \r didn't change anything, and the System.getProperty just added "null" everywhere.

Comment: Nevermind. It worked when I changed it to the order with \r\n. Thank you so much!

Comment: A line terminator is either `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`.  Not what you've shown here.